# PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT - Android Studio Erro

Tags: java, sqlite

Estou tentando inserir registros com auto incremento, porém toda vez tenho retorno de falha. Mas se é auto incremento ele não deveria me solicitar o quinto registro?

Código DataBase:

```
database1.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ssxx (idEvento INTEGER
PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT, data varchar(20),valor
varchar(20),descricao varchar(20),forma varchar(20));");
```

Código de Inclusão Funcional:

```
database1.execSQL("INSERT INTO ssxx VALUES('" + EDNome.getText() +
"','" + EDFone.getText() + "','" + EDesc.getText() + "','" +
radioButton.getText() + "')");
```

O Erro:

```
  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table ssxx has 5 columns but 4 values were supplied (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO ssxx VALUES('05/07/2019','11','q','Vista')
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
```

Ele diz que estou tentando inserir 4 registros, porém minha base de dados tem 5 campos. O auto increment não deveria preencher automaticamente o campo do id?

Comment: Se você quiser que um campo seja incluído com seu valor DEFAULT então este campo não pode aparecer na lista de campos. Em seu caso você precisa colocar a lista de campos para os quais está informando os valores. Vide a documentação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendo seu ponto de vista, mas vc deve especificar quais valores vc estará colocando na tabela na ordem. Vc pode (e deve) colocar somente os 4 valores que não correspondem ao seu id e deixar que o Banco de Dados cuide do autoincremento da seguinte maneira:

`database1.execSQL("INSERT INTO ssxx(data, valor, descricao, forma) VALUES('" + EDNome.getText() + "','" + EDFone.getText() + "','" + EDesc.getText() + "','" +
radioButton.getText() + "')");`

Se vc não especificar exatamente os 4 valores da tupla que esta querendo adicionar, o BD vai esperar que vc passe como parâmetro a quantidade de colunas que aquela tabela possui, e se vc passar alguma quantidade diferente disso ele não saberá o que fazer.

Por outro lado, se vc especificar os 4 valores, ele irá associar cara um dos parâmetros passados com suas respectivas colunas, e aquela que sobrou (o autoincrement) ele cuidará a parte

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: muito obrigado como não vi isso!! obrigado mesmo deu certinho!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode observar o INSERT que não está informando as colunas.

Exemplo de INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO people ( first_name, last_name ) VALUES  ( 'John', 'Smith' );
```

Referência: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-autoincrement/

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: De acordo com o manual deve ser AUTOINCREMENT.

Comment: Realmente, irei atualizar!